# Getting Error on Password Reset: Object of type SMTPSenderRefused is not JSON serializable

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-authentication, django-allauth

I am getting this issue on for my custom password reset view, User Model is email based.

```
#View.py
class PasswordResetView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = PasswordResetSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.data.get("email")
        try:
            User.objects.get(email=email)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={"request": request})
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serializer.save()
                return Response({
            "message": "An attempt to reset user password is successful. Please check your email inbox for more instructions.",
                    "status": "success",
                    "code": 200
        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as exc:
            return Response({
                "message": "Exception(s) occurred while attempting to send the email. Please look at the exception(s) and try again.",
                "exception": str(exc).strip('\n'),
                "status": "error",
                "code": 500
            }, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

I am trying to send password reset link through mail, after verifying if the user account exist on  our database